# Should Server Side Rendering be preferred in this case?

Tags: reactjs, spring-boot, spring-mvc, server-side-rendering

We have a Java Backend and React Client Side Rendering for now. The react act is server via ExpressJs backend. Now, we are planning to have SSR with the above architecture i.e

Java (Backend) -> Express Js (Front-End) -> Client Browser.

Now, looking at the above architecture it seems counter intuitive to me that SSR will be fast here as it involves following steps:

1. Fetch data from Java to ExpressJs (takes time ~t)
2. Use express to do SSR (take r time and send small bundle ~r' and html)
3. Fetch the same data + html from ExpressJs to Client (take time ~t)

Total Time (t):  2t + r + r'

Without SSR the flow should have been:

1. Send the JS bundle from express to client (time taken ~r'')
2. Send the data from Java to ExpressJs (time taken ~t)

Total Time (t'): t + r''

Comparing t and t' for SSR to be optimizing:

1. 2t + r + r' > t + r''
2. t + r + r' > r''

With above, If I am able to create a small bundle on each React app, I can actually have r'' ~ t + r + r', and this can be actually be done using React suspense (lazy component load) right?

Also, The First Contentful Paint (FCP) metric is better here but On subsequent loads, SSR is always slower then the Client side load.

However, I am still unable to conclude exactly when SSR will be a big boost for performance. I am unable to draw exact lines for switching between SSR and CSR.

**Questions**

1. Can someone refer me to good documentation for such arch. and if SSR is actually useful here ?
2. If SSR is of any use in such arch. where we have complete separate backend working as an individual service? What rules should be followed here?
3. With current understanding I feel that SSR is mostly useful for Static websites with less interactions.
4. With above, SSR only provides me with small bundles of JS which reduces load time, this I can do using "Dynamic Loading (suspense)" in react I believe?

**Note**

- SEO is irrelevant for my use-case.
- The time for data from backend server to frontend server is kept same as from front-end to cient on basis of internal network.